# Understanding Cookie Expiration - And How to Set

Tags: jquery, cookies, colorbox

I am using a cookie on my site to display colorbox one time on page load then after that the user has the option to manually load the colorbox each time. But what I do not understand is how you set the expiration date for the cookie. I got the needed code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086984/using-cookies-to-load-colorbox-on-first-page-load-only) here on SO and it would help if someone could explain to me what is what here.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){

   if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) 
   {
      var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
      var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
      document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
      $j.colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#gallery-nav-instruct"});
   }

});
```

I would assume this means the cookie expires in 15 days. How would I change this to longer? Say 30 or 60 days?

Comment: 30 days = 15 days * 2. Similar for 60 days. Are you sure you want to set it using javascript, rather than server side?

Comment: @user1012037 - I use a CMS without server side access so this is not currently possible. JS is how I must go.

Comment: Also what exactly do these combinations of numbers: `1000*60*60*24*15;` mean? And what would you change exactly to say do 60 days?

Comment: Those numbers are the total milliseconds in 15 days. To increase to 60 days, you multiply it again by 4 (15*4=60).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key thing to note here is

```
var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
```

**15** days each having **24** hours, each having **60** minutes, each having **60** seconds.

The last factor is 1000. so **fitteenday** variable is holding the number of **milliseconds** in 15 days.

```
var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
```

This statement implies the expiration date of the cookie is whatever current date is plus 15 days.

So in your case when you want expiration of **15** or **30** days, you just need to replace **15** with however days you have in mind

Comment: I have the same script. How would you go about setting the time to expire in fifteen minutes?

Comment: 15 Minutes would be this: new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + 15 * 60 * 1000)

Answer (score 2):

For all practical purposes here is a simple table.

```
var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + time);
```

where time = the following:

- **1 Millisecond:** time = 1
- **1 Second:** time = 1000
- **1 Minute:** time = 60 * 1000
- **1 Hour:**   time = 60 * 60 * 1000
- **1 Day(24 hours):** time = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
- **1 Average Month (29.6 Days):** time = 29.6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
- **1 Year (365.24):** time = 365.24 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

Comment: If one year is 365.24 days and also 12 months, the average amount of days is not 29.6, rather 365.24/12 = *30.4 days*