# Load Magnific Popup once every 15 days for new user

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup, jquery-cookie

I have a newsletter sign up form that I would like to load (popup) only one time every 15 days, otherwise it might get a bit annoying. I am currently using this jquery code to load the popup form when the page loads.

```html
<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
Popup Form
</div>

<script>
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
items: {src: '#test-popup'},type: 'inline'}, 0);
});
</script>
```

This works fine when loading the form every time you access the page but I would like to limit this so new users see it once every 15 days. Not sure if the 15 days is best practice just something I came up with?

Comment: I'd set a cookie to expire every 15 days. if it's false/expired. show the popup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103128/understanding-cookie-expiration-and-how-to-set

Comment: You should save it in a database

Comment: I used to use this cookie script with colorbox but I am wondering how to do it for  Magnific Popup?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
        var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*15;
        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
    $.colorbox({width:"480px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
        }
});
</script>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You [can](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) use [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute) to do this.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  var now, lastDatePopupShowed;
  now = new Date();

  if (localStorage.getItem('lastDatePopupShowed') !== null) {
    lastDatePopupShowed = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('lastDatePopupShowed')));
  }

  if (((now - lastDatePopupShowed) >= (15 * 86400000)) || !lastDatePopupShowed) {
    $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: { src: '#test-popup' },
      type: 'inline'
    }, 0);

    localStorage.setItem('lastDatePopupShowed', now);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="test-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
  Popup Form
</div>
```

You can see a working example here: http://codepen.io/caio/pen/Qwxarw

Comment: the 'localStorage' seems to be a pretty useful method.

Answer (score 1):

functions for create and read cookies:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
   else var expires = "";
   document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
       if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);

    }
    return null;
}
```

create a cookie for 15 days:

```
createCookie('run_popup',true,15);
```

check for elapsed 15 days

```
if(!readCookie('run_popup'))
... code for run popup...
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your popup open every 15 days for user you probably want to set a cookie that expires every 15 days. On your page, check if cookie has expired, if yes, show your form and reset your cookie.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery) you can find material for quick start with cookies.

That will work per browser per computer, ie if user opens your page in other browser, it will load your popup again.